# Посчитать кол-во понедельников в google таблице

Tags: дата, google-spreadsheet

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как посчитать количество понедельников в столбце с датами в google таблице?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через что вы хотите посчитать? ))
через формулу? через макросы? через google query ?

Comment: Любым способом. Если можно, опишите оба способа, думаю люди и я выберут кому что удобнее.

Answer (score 0):

как пример

1. определяем день недели каждой даты
2. считаем сколько понедельников в диапазоне

Формула для определения дня недели по дате: `ДЕНЬНЕД(A1)`

Формула для подсчета кол-ва понедельников:  `СЧЁТЕСЛИ(B1:B20;"=2")`

**Пример**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]